# What HttpStatusCode and ReasonPhase in Web API to return for defensive programming?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When writing a public function, I would generally follow the practices of defensive programming, like this.

```
    public long CreateSection(Section section)
    {
        if (section == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("section");

        var entityId = section.EntityId;
        if (entityId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("To add section, the entity must have already been saved with entityId", "section");

        Debug.Assert(section.Id == 0, "If someone give such section, I don't minid to save it.");

        ...
        return section.Id;
    }
```

I am going to wrap this up into an ASP.NET Web API 2.x function. Upon ArgumentExceptions, I think I need to throw HttpResponseException with a HttpStatusCode and ReasonPhase.

1. What HttpStatusCode should I use?
2. Should I overwrite the default ReasonPhase value with the argument name missing?
3. What is the best practice to handle the exceptions thrown in the API controller function and tell the clients?

Comment: Return whatever HTTP Status makes sense. For argument errors I usually return 400, Bad Request.

Comment: Bad Request is a good one. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As per personal oppinion,

1. I would use 400 Bad Request. 500 should be avoided cause you should handle the exceptions and thus it really isn't a complete breakdown.
2. Yes, it's always good to let the consumer know what they did wrong so they may correct their next request. If your service just went down in a shower of sparks, how are they to know what they did wrong?
3. Do not throw them. If you do, make sure you handle them to output something decent like the the `Application_Error` in `Global.asax` in the good old ASP projects. A clean 500 breakdown isn't very pretty after all :)